# Javascript: How to let user upload videos?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming

I’m trying to create a website where users can upload / watch videos, and leave comments on videos. So basically YouTube. I would prefer a method that let me scale my website, if it ever comes to that.

So far I have figured out how to display videos. But **how can I let users upload videos?**

**UPDATE:**

I am not a very skilled programmer and have no in-depth knowledge about anything, so maybe I should rephrase the question. What do you recommend me using for this. I am open to 3rd party tech and everything else?

For now im only focusing on the uploading aspect.
***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

    // Display video
    <video controls width="640" height="480"  autoplay >
    
        <source src="videoFile.mp4" type="video/mp4" >


    <!-- fallback for browsers that don't support mp4 -->
        <source src="videoFile.webm" type="video/webm">

    <!-- specifying subtitle files -->
        <track src="subtitles_en.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" 
        label="English" />

        <track src="subtitles_no.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="no" 
        label="Norwegian" />

    <!-- fallback for browsers that don't support video tag -->
        <a href="videoFile.mp4">download video</a>


    </video>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***main.js***

```
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");

if (myVideo.canPlayType("video/mp4")) {
  myVideo.setAttribute("src", "videoFile.mp4");
  console.log("first if");
} else if (myVideo.canPlayType("video/webm")) {
  myVideo.setAttribute("src", "videoFile.webm");
  console.log("second if");
}

myVideo.width = 480;
myVideo.height = 320;
```

Comment: You'll need to send the videos to your server and store them. As such, this isn't something that can be done just in client-side JS. If you Google 'upload file in xx' where xx is the language your server supports you'll find lots of tutorials covering this

Comment: I was told by someone that I need to use `node.js v18` and `expressjs v4` and `formidable v3` to be able to do this. Does that sound right?

Comment: This is a vast subject area that cannot reasonably be answered in the scope of a single answer. First you have the uploading. Your own server? Blob storage in a cloud provider? Something else? Then you have the encoding to make the video web-friendly. Doing this yourself? You'll need a deep understanding of video codecs, browser standards and so on, and some $erious computing grunt. Going third party? Now this question becomes a recommendation request and off-topic. Whichever way you cut it, this question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated my post, to make it more "recommendation-related". For the uploading aspect, what would you say is the best approach for someone with no knowledge about any of the mentioned things? @spender

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a few tutorials on setting up basic CRUD applications first.  Choose a js framework (or a couple) like react or vue, and follow along with some tutorials for setting up client & server side layouts in some basic react or vue stacks, like MERN stack for example.

https://aviyel.com/post/1278/crafting-a-stunning-crud-application-with-mern-stack

Once you have the hang of running a client side app and a server (like a node server that you had mentioned), and sending & receiving info between the two, then you work on having your server store that info in a database and respond with proper status codes & info back to the client side.

Once you can do that with simple things like getting & posting messages or images, then you can start researching sending files through those same methods.

Answer (score 0):

First  you'll need a form containing an [input with **type="file"** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)
, then, on form submit, you need to handle uploaded files on backend (e.g. PHP, Node.js or anything you like to use).

Then, in the backend, you have to implement your own logic, then just save the video to your storage and save name of the video or path to the video in your database, so you know which file you will need to serve to user on frontend.

Be aware that this is really advanced thing to do (you have to deal with bandwidth, security and so on), so if you really want to do it still, the best solution for you is to use some third party service for the backend part.

## Recommendation

You mentioned that you are not so skilled yet, so I would recommend you service like [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/), which can offer an API for uploading (so you will probably still need to create some backend part), or you can use their [widgets](https://cloudinary.com/blog/video_uploads_with_cloudinary) right on the frontend, so all you have to do is just create a frontend and implement their widget for upload and they will take care of everything.

Hope this helps you, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do I understand this right? If I use the Cloudinary upload API, I will have to  create my own backend. But if I use the widgets I only need to implement the widgets on the front end and then the API does the rest for me?

Comment: Yes, looks to me like that, you should be able to avoid the backend completely because you can to add custom tags when uploading and then when you need to render a specific video for your users, you can use [Search API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api), _otherwise, right after uploading you will receive response with an absolute URL of the video, so you can send it to your own backend and store it to your db)._ It depends on your needs and skill and app needs. It's not best practice, but probably the simplest and the most secure way for you at this point.

Comment: Okay so one of these following scenarios are true. After using the API I can upload the video on then get an URL, which I need to store in my own database. What DB do you recommend? And when wanting to display the video I get the URL from my own DB and display it. OR I don’t have to store anything myself, because the API does everything. Which one is true?

Comment: Both of them are possible ways how to do it, you can use Cloudinary just as a video hosting and storing needed info in your own DB (choose of db is also up to you, you can use MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle DB, some NoSQL dbs, it doesn't matter), or you can store every details of videos in Cloudinary as tags and then use Search API, but you will probably still need to store users data, so you can't avoid own backend and db, you can avoid using own backend + db just for the video storing part. Maybe you should start with simplier app, or at least design app an db scheme and move slowly to achieve it